# Which is the best way to compare django models textarea field value edits?

Tags: python, django

I have a requirement case where I need to preserve the values of the model textField field(example: `comments = models.TextField`  to be visible in history in the model admin form. How do I do that in django 1.6? Is there any plugin available? I have seen the fieldtracker with pre_save and post_save methods, but it does not serve my use case.

Comment: The term you are probably looking for is "versioning" https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/versioning/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store versioned history of Field in a Django model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540111/store-versioned-history-of-field-in-a-django-model)