# Django - Keeping history of a field

Tags: python, django

Using django 1.7 admin page, I want to Person objects to have a unique Note while keeping the history of the Note field.
Here is my code:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    note = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.note


class NoteHist(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    note = models.ForeignKey('Note')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.note)


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    note = models.ForeignKey('NoteHist')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Firstly, when pushing the save button on the Note dialog, the popup window redirects to a blank page as if it's broken; but I can refresh the main admin page to list the note.
Seondly, the notes are not Person specific. I mean Person2 can select Notes written by Person1.
I just want display the last note written by a specific Person while keeping the history of his notes.
By the way, I do not need to show the history in the admin page if that makes it easier.
Please guide me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to create a new instance of NoteHist every time you update the Note object by overriding the "save" method of Note.

Here's a similar question: [Store versioned history of Field in a Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540111/store-versioned-history-of-field-in-a-django-model)

Apparantly, there is a package that stores Django model state on every create/update/delete and also supports integration with django admin: https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history

Comment: I tried the solution to that "similar" question. It gives me an error: TypeError: 'RenameBaseModelAdminMethods' object is not iterable. I shall try simple-history.

Comment: I haven't tried the package myself. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks. django-simple-history works fine in the admin page and you can still apply search and filter to the admin page.