# Django Admin, Call function on save

Tags: python, django

I have a app in my Django site that handles blog post. When a blog post is published I want to schedule a Newsletter on a third party application that informs the subscribers of the new post.

So I want to add a custom function to be called when the blog post is saved where I can write this API call to the newsletter service.

How to do this? Tried looking through the documentations and all I can find is Admin Actions which doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Django Signals is what you are looking for. [Post save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) is pretty useful for you.

Comment: U can use save method in model. That is easy for your work. Within that def django huey can use for queue.                                                                                                                                                def save(self):

  super(ModelName,self).save()

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a number of approaches you could use.

Override the model save method is simple, but will be called every time the model is saved.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects

If it is specific to the admin site, in your ModelAdmin use the model_save() method. (I like this approach personally, as it won't interfere with your model).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

You could also use a post save signal, but save methods seem to be preferred (depending on what you are doing) [Django: When to customize save vs using post-save signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597378/django-when-to-customize-save-vs-using-post-save-signal)

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely go for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save, which provides the complete functionality that you are looking for here.

Comment: will it work when we will save object from admin side?