# django signals or override save method?

Tags: django, django-signals

This question aims for best practises. So I have a model A and model B.
model B has model A as foreign key but whenever a new instance of model A is created a new instance of model B has to be created and linked with that instance of model A.

Currently I have resolved the circular dependecy by referencing all foreign key models with strings and I override the save function of model A to check if a link to model B is already present and if not it creates one. But I'm not sure if this is the best thing to do.

Should I use a signal instead, so that whenever model A is saved a signal is received by post_save which checks if that instance already has a model B instance linked to it and if not creates it?

My only concern with signals is that they seem to take some time and I have to be sure that model B instance is created immediately.

Comment: Signals don't take any more time than anything else.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman maybe I was doing something wrong the last time I implemented stuff with signals. If this is the case I will go with the signal method since it's a bit more clear and cleaner

Comment: There's no right answer to this, only opinions. It's mostly a matter of code organization, rather than technical differences, and people just can't seem to agree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: When to customize save vs using post-save signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597378/django-when-to-customize-save-vs-using-post-save-signal)